# Draw polygons on new added Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Folks,

I need to insert a specific Google map image of a mining plant from a customer.
Viewing the Google documentation we were able to adjust the client image, we used Custom Overlay for that matter.

Well, we are not able to draw on top of the image added via "Overley", for example creation of Polygons.

We are using this example of Google itself.
[Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple?hl=pt-br)

Is it possible to draw on an added image in Google Maps?

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Drawing Manager over custom overlay image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339034/using-drawing-manager-over-custom-overlay-image)

Answer (score 0):

I got it here. It was the order in which I was mounting my map.

Thank you for your help